# Databricks scala cannot find uber objects

Tags: scala, databricks

First allow me to say, I am trying to learn Databricks but have years of Data Factory and ETL experience.  I got some code that uses AIS data to map logistics movements.

The code uses Uber libraries for H3Core functionality. I did see a demo of this code on a coworkers laptop so **I know it CAN work**.

I am having trouble finding the uber objects.  I assume this is a newbie thing. I imagine my problem is environmental.

I cannot post all the code but the include lines that are throwing the error:

```
import com.uber.h3core.H3Core
import com.uber.h3core.util.GeoCoord
import com.uber.h3core.LengthUnit
```

Those lines produce the following errors on execution:

```
command-2206228078162026:1: error: object uber is not a member of package com
import com.uber.h3core.H3Core
           ^
command-2206228078162026:2: error: object uber is not a member of package com
import com.uber.h3core.util.GeoCoord
           ^
command-2206228078162026:3: error: object uber is not a member of package com
import com.uber.h3core.LengthUnit
       ^
```

Below I think it is trying to reference objects created with missing class libraries for H3Core:

```
command-2206228078162026:15: error: not found: value H3Core
  val h3 = H3Core.newInstance()
           ^
command-2206228078162026:26: error: not found: value H3Core
  val h3 = H3Core.newInstance()
           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also had similar issues, usually occurring when the size of the jar is a little bigger where in the notebook starts running before the jar is fully loaded. But I have not been able to reproduce it consistently. (So don't quote the answer on it.)

Couple of Options we have tried. Please validate and see if it work for you.

1. Have the jar available on the DBFS path and then install it from DBFS as a dependent library at the job level. Please refer to the link - [Dependent-Libraries](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/jobs/jobs.html#dependent-libraries)
2. We have seen that sometimes even this fails. If it is possible, you can check if the library has been loaded and sleep and then check again. Not sure how you would do that in scala.

Please validate what works....
Cheers...